# Log scale on D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

I'm trying to use a scale to draw an audio waveform. The linear scale is too "dynamic", and I'd like to apply a compression on the peaks. I thought about a log scale, although I really don't know how to use it in D3.

Linear scale:

```js
      // Scale for time
      xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([0,samples_length]).range([0,width]);

      // Scale for samples
      yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([-1,0,1]).range([0,height]);

      let area = d3.area()
                  .x(function(d, i){return xScale(i)})
                  .y0(function(d){return yScale(d); })
                  .y1(function(d){return height-yScale(d); });

      let waveform = d3.select("#waveform")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height);

      waveform.append("path")
              .attr("d", area(samples))
              .attr("fill", "steelblue");
```

The linear scale gives me:

[image]

And I'd like something more like this:
[image]

I also tried the Symlog scale:

```js
      // Scale for time
      xScale = d3.scaleSymlog()
                .domain([0,samples_length]).range([0,width]);

      // Scale for samples
      yScale = d3.scaleSymlog()
                .domain([-1,0,1]).range([0,height]);

      let area = d3.area()
                  .x(function(d, i){return xScale(i)})
                  .y0(function(d){return yScale(d); })
                  .y1(function(d){return height-yScale(d); });

      let waveform = d3.select("#waveform")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height);

      waveform.append("path")
              .attr("d", area(samples))
              .attr("fill", "steelblue");
    }
```

And the Symlog gives me:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't scale the time with symlog, only the volume, as decibels is a non-linear scale, but time is linear

Comment: Thanks! that solved the problem with the Symlog scale drawing incorrectly. The drawing is still too dynamic :(. Any suggestion on that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the dynamic plot by simply reducing the scale range:

```js
      // Scale for samples
      yScale = d3.scaleSymlog()
                .domain([-1,0,1])
                .range([0,height/4])
                .constant(-1);
```

The final result looks more pleasant:

[image]